# SharedMemory.BufferReadWrite corrupting (cutting) data

Tags: c#, ipc

I am trying to use SharedMemory package to share data between two C# apps written in C# .Net 3.5 (unfortunately cannot upgrade). I wrote a simple test to see how it works

```
    private void runTest()
    {
        string testText = "someTest";   //"some", "someTest12"
        CreateOrOpenMappedFile(testText);
        string result = ReadMemoryMappedFile();
    }
    
    protected void CreateOrOpenMappedFile(string data)
    {
        char[] dataBuffer = data.ToCharArray();
        SharedMemory.BufferReadWrite buff = new SharedMemory.BufferReadWrite("sharedMemoryName", 4096);
        buff.Write(dataBuffer);
    }

    protected string ReadMemoryMappedFile()
    {
        char[] data = new char[10];         
        SharedMemory.BufferReadWrite buff = new SharedMemory.BufferReadWrite("sharedMemoryName");
        buff.Read(data);
        buff.Close();
        return new string(data);
    }
```

In runTest method I expected testText string to be the same as result, but what I was getting was a string that was clipped. For testText == "someTest" result was "some", for "some", result was "so", for "someTest12" it was "someT".
What could be happening here?
Marek

Comment: What is the implementation of `BufferReadWrite()`?

Comment: Don't know the package but from similar scenarios this might be related to an incomplete write. Check if BufferReadWrite uses IDiposable and if so wrap it in using statement. You can also use P/Invoke to use OS functions for that (used that approach for years)

Comment: Given that the first occurrence of `pointData` is in your call to `Read` this code shouldn't compile. Please make sure your sample *compiles and exhibits the problem you want to ask about*.

Comment: In addition to what TomB said, look for a `Flush()` method instead if disposing the MMF closes it and makes it impossible to open for read subsequently.

Comment: Damien - sorry, that was a miss-spell. Obviously both should be the same, I changed it in the question.
TomB - wrapping BufferReadWrite in using closes the memory file after writing, so trying to read it throws an exception.

Comment: That's because this library is buggy. It uses `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T))`, and when you pass in a type of `char`, which is a 16-bit unicode code point in memory, it returns a size of 1, so you end up storing only half the bytes. I would find a different library, or if you still want to use it, find a way to report a bug in the library. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30320 for more information.

Comment: In fact, I believe this library is potentially dangerous to use, it allows passing `<T>` through this memory, and that is definitely not safe. It should've focused on basic primitives where the known outcome was fixed, instead of *any random type*, which is likely to not work when being memory blitted back into arrays. You should find something else.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is solved by converting the string to byte[] rather than char[].
The answer was provided in [github repository of this library](https://github.com/spazzarama/SharedMemory/issues/57) by its author.